# servlet - choosing the file to download on clicking a link

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

The scenario is like : I have a page on which when we submit a file number, the client is given a link to download the file. But I don't know how to write one servlet which will decide which file to send to the client. This has to happen on clicking of a link, so I can't send parameters which can help me determine which file to download.

Please help.

Comment: a) Why clicking on a link you can't send parameters? b) How would you write a non-servlet method that decides which file to serve?

Comment: a) yes, we can send parameters, but i dint know that :P
b) I am using a servlet to decide which file to send

Comment: about b) the question is: if you ignore that it is a servlet, how would you do that? solve this problem and the rest is just about binding to the servlet.

Comment: yes, I understand that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you submit a file number;
2. you build a link based on that file number (it's a link for a GET. GET can have parameters, so you can put parameters in the URL path or in the query string);
3. user clicks the link;
4. the link is handled by a servlet;
5. the servlet uses the parameters from the GET request to determine what file to send;
6. you send the content of that file in the response.

Those are the steps.

Here is an example on BalusC's blog: http://balusc.blogspot.ro/2007/07/fileservlet.html

What you need to take care of is security:

- don't expose the file directly as path on the server otherwise users can navigate the path to access other files on your application;
- if users of your application have different rights, make sure you check those rights before returning the file, so that you a user can't access somebody else's files.